# Usage of "had" in this context

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, perfect-aspect

- We had better get out of here before they see us.

Is "**had**" absolutely necessary here? Will the sentence be correct without "**had**":

- We better get out of here before they see us.

Comment: Some speakers say "We better {VERB}" but they would also be likely to say **ain't**.  I take the tense as a backshift reflecting the exhortation (a preterite of modal remoteness).

Comment: Every sentence needs a verb. *had* is the verb in your sentence, so you need it if you want the sentence to be grammatically correct. Beyond that I can't help you. Maybe the comment @Tᴚoɯɐuo is right but I don't understand what he's saying.

Comment: @Readin He's saying that without "**had**" it is as incorrect as saying "**ain't**".

Comment: I suppose you could argue that **better** is becoming a modal verb. Many speakers use it like **should**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo So basically "*You better study*"="*You should study*" by many speakers?

Comment: "You better study for that exam" = I *strongly advise you* to study for that exam.   It is almost a warning.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWv72L4wgCc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between descriptive grammar and prescriptive grammar. Descriptive grammar tells you how English is used. Prescriptive grammar tells you how most well-educated people believe it *should* be used.

"We better" is wrong according to prescriptive grammar.

"We better" is fine according to descriptive grammar because many native speakers say it.

So if you are trying to pass a TOEFL, write an academic essay or research paper, or do anything else where you want to appear to be well-educated, you had better include the "had" in  your sentence.

By Googling it, I find support:
https://ruthlesseditor.com/you-better-vs-you-had-better/

> When you are suggesting that someone should or ought to do something, the correct was to say it is had better

https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/109638-You-better-or-You-d-better

> For people speaking carefully, the "d" is there, but it gets "swallowed" in fast speech.
>
> Make sure you keep it in your writing.